# JSON to Angular2+ Single Page Application creation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, single-page-application

I want to produce an Angular js application based on JSON provided as below -

```
{
  name: 'App Name',
  pages: [ 
    { name: 'Home', url: '/',
      layout: { 
         type:'HTMLElement'
         tag:'div',
         attr: {},
         children:[
           {
             type: 'AngularComponent',
             tag:'hello-world',
             attr: {},
             children:[]
           }
         ]
      } 
   },
    ...page2 , page 3 etc...
  ]

}
```

This I can do with angularJs1.x but I find it very difficult to do the same using angular2.

I don't want to rely on angular-cli for this.
I want every thing to be in JavaScript not typescript because code generation for pages in typescript can cause problem.
The angular2 compilation process takes time, even for the preview I have to wait for more than 10 seconds where in angularjs it is immediate.
Size of the application is huge i.e 3MB+ in this case.

Any suggestion and recommendation on this.
Thanks

Comment: Then stick with AngularJS. Angular (2 or 4) are based on Typescript, if you don't want to use Typescript then you don't want to use Angular.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options :

- Stay on AngularJS (= 1.x)
- Create a separate library (maybe without using AngularJS or Angular)
- Optimize your code design : create sub modules, compile them separately but this may bring other issues
- Optimize your environment : switch to SSD or RAMDISK